# Aggregation/correlation with multiple IDs

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables usr and rslt as below.

[image]

I want to get output as below.

[image]

I have tried below query to get total wins & lost

```
SELECT    tab1.id
       , tab1.wins
       , tab2.loos
FROM
        (SELECT u1.ID
             , COUNT(r1.WINNER) wins
         FROM   rslt r1
             , usr u1
         WHERE  (u1.ID = r1.WINNER)
         GROUP BY u1.ID) tab1
       ,
        (SELECT u2.ID
             , COUNT(r2.Looser) loos
         FROM   rslt r2
             , usr u2
         WHERE  (u2.ID = r2.Looser)
         GROUP BY u2.ID) tab2
WHERE tab1.ID = tab2.id;
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: given the sample data, how did you get to that output? maybe explain you `RSLT` table so it is clear what each field represents

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the correlated query, the performance could be bad if there are a lot of usrs as each query is run per row that is in the usr table, but, you should get the idea.

```
   select 
      id, name, 
      (select count(*) c
       from rslt
       where
         (rslt.sender = usr.id or rslt.receiver = usr.id) and
         rslt.winner = usr.id) wins, 
      (select count(*) c
       from rslt
       where
         (rslt.sender = usr.id or rslt.receiver = usr.id)) played, 
      (select count(*) c
       from rslt
       where
         (rslt.sender = usr.id or rslt.receiver = usr.id) and
         rslt.looser = usr.id) lost, 
      (select count(*) c
       from rslt
       where
         (rslt.sender = usr.id or rslt.receiver = usr.id) and
         rslt.tie <> 'T') tie
    from usr;
```

**Result when I ran the query:**

[image]

Table creation DML below, if any one want to fiddle

```
create table usr(id number,name varchar(10));

create table rslt (id number,sender number, receiver number,winner number,looser number, tie varchar(1));

insert into usr values(1,'Prince');

insert into  usr values(2,'Subham');

insert into usr values(3,'3');

insert into rslt values(1,1,2,2,1,'T');

insert into rslt values(2,2,3,3,2,'T');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it without using a bunch of correlated queries, which would likely be tougher to optimize properly:

```
SELECT
    u.ID
    ,u.NAME
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.SENDER = u.ID THEN 1 else 0 END + CASE WHEN r.RECEIVER = u.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TotalPlayed'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.WINNER = u.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'TotalWins'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (r.SENDER = u.ID OR r.RECEIVER = u.ID) AND r.WINNER <> u.ID THEN 1 else 0 END) as 'TotalLost'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (r.SENDER = u.ID OR r.RECEIVER = u.ID) AND r.TIE <> 'T' THEN 1 else 0 END) as 'TotalTie'
FROM USR u
LEFT JOIN RSLT r
ON u.ID = r.SENDER OR u.id = r.RECEIVER
GROUP BY u.ID, u.NAME
ORDER BY u.ID
```

That works in SQL Server, I think it should be OK for Oracle (which you seem to be working in)

Output:

```
id          name       TotalPlayed TotalWins   TotalLost   TotalTie
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           Prince     1           0           1           0
2           Subham     2           1           1           0
3           3          1           1           0           0
4           4          0           0           0           0
5           5          0           0           0           0
6           6          0           0           0           0
7           7          0           0           0           0
8           8          0           0           0           0
```